# Why do these images appear on top of each other not in rows? [HTML][CSS][Bootstrap]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap's grid to display two rows each with two images like so:

```html
<section class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <figure class="column-sm-6">
             <p>floor plan</p>
             <img src="floorplan.jpg">
         </figure>
         <figure class="column-sm-6">
             <p>kitchen</p>
             <img src="kitchen.jpg">
         </figure>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <figure class="column-sm-6">
             <p>outdoor bath</p>
             <img src="outdoorbath.jpg">
         </figure>
         <figure class="column-sm-6">
             <p>bedrooms</p>
             <img src="bedroom.jpg">
         </figure>
     </div>
 </section>
```

But they are appearing on top of each other as you can see when you run the code snippet. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

Change your class from

```
<div class="column-sm-6"> </div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-6"> </div>
```

Bootstrap's default column class is "col"

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bootstrap 4 or higher and if you want the columns to be of equal spaces each then just under the **row** div define every column div's class as **class="col"**

it will distribute the row space equally among the columns
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Solution to your problem will be the below given code.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <figure class="col-sm-6">
             <p>floor plan</p>
             <img src="floorplan.jpg">
         </figure>
         <figure class="col-sm-6">
             <p>kitchen</p>
             <img src="kitchen.jpg">
         </figure>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <figure class="col-sm-6">
             <p>outdoor bath</p>
             <img src="outdoorbath.jpg">
         </figure>
         <figure class="col-sm-6">
             <p>bedrooms</p>
             <img src="bedroom.jpg">
         </figure>
     </div>
 </section>
```